# WordPress post arrangement using post_class

Tags: theme-development, themes, post-class

I want to create post layout in the following way:

```
+--------------------+
| 1 Full Width Post  |
+----------+---------+
| 2        | 3       |
+--------------------+
| 4 Full Width Post  |
+----------+---------+
| 5        | 6       |
+----------+---------+
```

So basically I want to use the `post_class()`. Say for full width it will be "full-width" class and for half width it will be "half-width" class.

I was able to add even/odd class by this method:

```
function alternating_post_class( $classes ) {
   global $wp_query;
   $classes[] = ( $wp_query->current_post % 2 === 0 ? 'odd' : 'even' ); 
   return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'alternating_post_class');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just take a little bit more complicated logic:

```
function alternating_post_class($classes) {
  static $counter = 1;
  switch ($counter) {
    case 1:
      $classes[] = 'full-width';
      break;
    case 2:
    case 3;
      $classes[] = 'half-width';
      break;
  }
  $counter = ($counter == 3) ? 1 : $counter + 1;
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'alternating_post_class');
```